# How to run python script in background using Anaconda? ('nohup python -u test.py &' doesn't work!)

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, git-bash

I have a simple python script **test.py**:

```
import time
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)
i=0

while i<100:
    i+=1
    logging.info(i)
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I want to run this script in background using anaconda. I tried :`nohup python -u test.py &`.
**python** keyword invokes anaconda on my machine. It seems that script is still linked to the terminal I used to run it. If I close the terminal, the execution stops and if I use 'exit' to close the terminal, the terminal turns black but doesn't close. If I close using 'X', the execution stops.

What is the correct way to trigger a python script to run on anaconda in background?

```
$ conda info

     active environment : None
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.20.5
         python version : 3.8.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : F:\Automation\Anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Terminal used to run script: **Git**, version: **2.29.2.windows.3**

Answer (score 3):

Use the python executable of your conda environment.

1. run conda info to get the path to the base environment:<base_environment_path>
2. to use specific env, use its name and then access the python bin executable:
3. `nohup <base_environment_path>/envs/<env-name>/bin/python <script_name>.py`

e.g.

```
nohup /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python test.py > output.txt &
```

Comment: Can you explain what the & operator do at the end of the line? Thanks :)

Comment: The & operator is what tells bash to run the command in the background.  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet

Answer (score 1):

You will need to know the path to the python executable in the environment you want to execute the code in.

You can find that by running

> conda info

in your desired environment. When you find the location of environment you just have to to do this:

```
nohup <absolute path to your anaconda environment>/bin/python <YOUR SCRIPT> > output.txt &
```

If you don't want to use conda info to find it you can just execute this

```
nohup <absolute path to your anaconda>/anaconda3/envs/<your environment>/bin/python <YOUR SCRIPT> > output.txt &
```